# How to make values in output csv file separated instead at the same column

Tags: python, csv, output, txt

I have this line of code:

```py
self.tpub.write(np.array2string(self.PubMatrix[:,0], separator='\n', max_line_width=np.inf)[1:-1] + '\t' + TmAr + '\n')
```

Which .txt output looks like this:

[image: 1]

But when I changed output type to .csv in my code:

```py
self.tpub = open(CurrTime.strftime('%d %m %H %M') + "_2 TiPub.csv","w+")
```

The result is not the same for csv as it was in txt type:

[image: 2]

I wonder how to make that last value in csv file separated into next column likes it was in .txt file

Comment: Change separator in Excel from coma to tabulation

Comment: Can you post the file contents as text and not as an Excel screenshot? The Excel import might also play a role in this.

Comment: lol really sorry for wasting your time but thank  guys, I tried many ways but certainly forgot that a comma ',' in csv file could be that powerful. I have just replaced '\t' to ',' and it fixed everything as demanded.

Answer (score 0):

*Adding answer originally edited into the question on behalf of NatL*

---

I did not pay enough attention so, .csv type reads `','` as `'\t'` in .txt file so replacing `','` fixed the issue.